# Odoo how to dynamically create a weekly schedule mod-fri and mon-fri depending on a field inter value

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-view

I  have  a  task  that  has  been  giving  head ache  , kindly really appreciate  some  help .
**TASK** :

- Model  A  to Model  B  have  a  many2many relation .
- In  Model  B  which has a many2many  relation,i have a Integer field.
- If  the field  integer  is  3 or  more  , for each line of the  line items  added  using  the  many2many  items ,  generate  dynamically  weekly schedules meaning  if  the  integer  value  is  3  generate  three  weeks  dynamically  for  all  the  line items  in the many2many if the  field  is  4  for  each  line  items  generate 4  week to schedule on .

I have  tried  using a  wizard to  no  avail  .
Ways  of  solving  i  think  could  be  of  help  but  i  havent  been  able  successfully make  it  work is  using  the  fields_view_init() , fields_view_get() , using  context  where  i pick the  value of  the  integer  fields in  model  B  of the  many to  many  relation  and  using  @api.onchange and  @api.depends -- pull  the value of the  integer  field and  may  be  using the  fields_view_get() dynamically  create  the  two  weeks  schedule  or  the  3  three  weeks  depending  on the  integer  value  .

How  can i  achieve ,  please some  code examples are  highly appreciated  .
This code  below will  help  understand  what  i  mean  above

```
class  ratecard_sin_radio(models.Model):
    code  = fields.Char(string='SINGULAR RATECARD CODE',readonly=True)
    name  =   fields.Char(string='NAME')
    outlet_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='outlet', string='Outlet')
    timeband_id  = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='timeband', string='TimeBand')


class  ratecard_multiple(models.Model):
    #pudb.set_trace()
    _name = 'ratecard.multiple'
    scheduled_for  = fields.Integer(string='SCHEDULED FOR',default=1 ,track_visibility='always',store=True , readonly=True)

    multiple_ratecard_id  = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='ratecard.sin.radio', relation='ratecard_multiple_singular_rel',
                                                    column1='ratecard_multiple_id',
                                                    column2='ratecard_sin_radio_id', 
                                                    string='RATECARDS')
```

Sample part  of the view  i  have  :

```
  <group colspan="4"  col="4" >
<tree  editable="bottom">
        <group colspan="2"  col="2" >
             <field name='name'/>

            <field name="scheduled_for"/>
              </group>

        <field name='multiple_ratecard_id' nolabel="1" options="{'reload_on_button': true}">  <!-- widget="many2many"-->
        <tree  string="ALLOCATE SPOTS" editable="bottom">
                            <!--<field name="week_id" widget="one2many_list"/>-->
                         <button name="scheduler" string="SCHEDULE" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                           <field name="code"/>
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="outlet_id" on_change="onchange_outlet(outlet_id)" placeholder="OUTLET"/>
                             <field name="outlet_type_id" domain="[('outlet_id', '=' ,outlet_id)]" placeholder="OUTLET TYPE" />

                             <field name='monday'/>
                            <field name='tuesday'/>
                            <field name='wednesday'/>
                            <field name='thursday'/>
                            <field name='friday'/>
                            <field name='saturday'/>
                             <field name='sunday'/>
                             <field name="spot_total"/>
                             <field name="noofweeks"/>
                           <field name='allocate_subtotal'/>
                           <field name="rates_total"/>
                          <field name="total_cost"/>
        </tree>
      </field>
```

The button scheduler is  a  function  that  now  depends  on  scheduled_for  to  dynamically  generate  the  weekly  views  that is  if scheduled_for is 3
then  dynamically  i  generate  mon- sun  mon - sun  mon-sun  .  if
4  then  i  generate  mon  -sun  mon-sun  mon-sun  mon-sun

On  the 
 `<button name="scheduler" string="SCHEDULE" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>`

calls  this  function  which  creates a week. Problem  i  need  to  control  this  week  to  be  generated  according  to  the
 `scheduled_for` value  such  that  if  `scheduled_for` is  3  i return  a  week  calendar  model  that  have  3  weeks that  is  mon-sun  ,  mon-sun  ,  mon -sun  if  it the `scheduled_for` is  4 then  i return mon-sun  ,  mon-sun  ,  mon -sun  , mon-sun

```
@api.multi
def scheduler(self):
    view_id = self.env.ref('ragtimeorder.view_week_form').id
#   context = self._context.copy()
    return {
            'name':_('SCHEDULE RATECARD'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'views': [(view_id, 'form'), ],
            'res_model': 'week',
           # 'context': self._context,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',
            'flags': {'action_buttons': True},
}
```

Problem  with  this  scheduler  function  is  static which it  is  required  to  be  dynamic

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output.

Comment: I do not understand: do you have a form for model A which shows a field of model B? In the form of model B you have another many2many field for model, say C? depending of rows of C (say ROWS) and integer field (say N), you need  to create ROWS x N weeks of schdeuling?

Comment: @Odedra,@Alessandro  ,  kindly  i  have  added  the  code  for  better  understanding

Comment: what's in the 'monday' field etc.?

Comment: @AlessandroRuffolo the  monday  field  contains  can  be  a  date  or a  0  or  1  , mon-sun  --  i  use  this  to  schedule

Comment: @danielmwai so you need to generate the rows in multiple_ratecard_id depending on field! Am I right?

Comment: @AlessandroRuffolo ,  not the  rows ,   the  scheduler button  that  calls  the  function  scheduler returns a  view  with a   model  week  ,  kindly  i  have  made  an  edit  ,  please  check  ,Now  on the  scheduler  takes  the  value  of the  schedule_for  value  such  that  if its  3  it  will dynamically  create  3  weeks  in  the  view  when  the  button  is clicked  if  the  value of the  schedule_for is  changed  to  4  then  it  dynamically creates  a  4  weeks and that  will  happen  for each  row  in  the  multiple_ratecard_id

Answer (score 0):

@danielmwai

Their are multiple possible solution possible here, that you can employee:

1) Every time you schedule you create a database record for all possible event (sold and persistent solution but lot of over head)

2) You can virtually create records using `read/search_read` methods, every time some one ask for record you read that record and create virtual record pass in the view as views re dump it will render values and return according and  when you get back data for write then over ride `write` method and remove virtual record and handle them on code. (fast but can misbehaves some times)

3) You can write web module and let JS do the magic and do all event rendering though website interface module.

Bests